# Segmentation fault 11 building Clang SourceManager

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am trying to work with Clang's `CompilerInstance` class to do code-completion, but I am getting a segmentation fault with a basic program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"

int main() 
{
  auto compiler = new clang::CompilerInstance();

  compiler->createFileManager();
  compiler->createSourceManager(compiler->getFileManager());

  return 0;
}
```

> Segmentation fault: 11

I assume that I'm misunderstanding how memory is managed here.

What is the correct way to create a `CompilerInstance` with source and file managers?

Comment: Does the "new" return a valid pointer or null?

Comment: @Bruce The "default" `new` operator throws an exception if it fails to allocate memory, it will never return a null pointer.

Comment: It is a valid pointer; if I comment out `compiler->createSourceManager(compiler->getFileManager());`, then the code will finish.

Comment: So it is probably getFileManager() returning a null

Comment: Yes, `getFileManager()` is returning `null`. So the follow up question is, does `createFileManager()` do?